# Angular callback function preventing result to be displayed out of its function

Tags: angularjs, sqlite, cordova-plugins

When i run this script, it display 0 instead of the value from qty column in sales table. I want it to display the value from the qty column which is 20.

```
 $scope.wremain=0;
     var query = "SELECT * FROM sales WHERE buy_id=2";
     $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, []).then(function(success) {
        $scope.wremain=success.rows.item(0).qty;
 }, function (error) {alert("Error retrieving value");});

 alert($scope.wremain);
```

I will be grateful for any suggestion that will assist me achieve my goal.
Thank you for your time in advance

Answer (score 0):

try this, since you are dealing with async functions, you need to wait until you get a response.

```
$scope.wremain=0;
     var query = "SELECT * FROM sales WHERE buy_id=2";
     $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, []).then(function(success) {
        $scope.wremain=success.rows.item(0).qty;
        alert($scope.wremain);
 }, function (error) {alert("Error retrieving value");});
```

Comment: or you can use promises with $q.  Then you can carry over the result anywhere you want.

Comment: Thank za. it works well when alert($scope.wremain); is inside the function but when its outside the function, it doesn't work

Comment: well, as I said :)  it won't work outside.  There is an async operation you have to wait for.  Read about promises and you will understand.

Comment: Thank you za for the direction towards promises with $q